# Mysql between two date from other fields

Tags: mysql

I have on my first table the evolution of the price for all article with the first date which define the date where change price..  ''evolution_price''

```
article -- date  ----- unit.price  
1 ---  2012-01-01 -- 1.20  
1 ---  2013-01-01 -- 1.10  
1 ---  2014-01-01 -- 1.20  
2 ---  2012-01-01 -- 1.40  
2 ---  2013-01-01 -- 1.50  
2 ---  2014-01-01 -- 1.20
```

on my second table liste of order history (forget unit price 0.00)  ''orders''

```
article-- date---- price unit --- total order  
1 ----- 2012-02-03 -- 0.00 -------- 12.10  
2 ----- 2012-02-05 -- 0.00 -------- 15.20   
1 ----- 2013-01-01 -- 0.00 -------- xxx   
1 ----- 2014-05-05 -- 0.00  
1 ----- 2014-05-06 -- 0.00
```

I am looking for include the right unit price on the second table but egal on between two right date.. the evolution of price can be 20 date/price the price must be between (date1 to date2)price and (2date to 3date)price ... etc..;
second table desired ''orders'':

```
1 ----- 2012-02-03 -- 1.20 ----- 12.10  
2 ----- 2012-02-05 -- 1.20 ----- 15.20  
1 ----- 2013-01-01 -- 1.10 ----- xxx
```

I test this one

`update orders
     set orders.unit_price =
     (
     select 
     unit_price
     from evolution_price
     where 
     orders.article_id = evolution_price.article_id
     and 
     orders.order_date >= evolution_price.change_date
     order 
     by evolution_price.change_date desc limit 1
     );`

Comment: The answer from Turophile is what I search... I search now how direct update the second table with update and set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I think you want something like this:

```
select 
  article_id ,
  order_date ,
  unit_price  as old_unit_price,
  order_total,
  (select unit_price
   from evolution as e
   where o.article_id = e.article_id
   and change_date <= order_date
   order by change_date desc
   limit 1 ) as new_unit_price
from orders as o
```

Here it is working in a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/414e8/3

Note that your question should be tagged `sql` and not tagged `between`,`table` or `data`.

It is great that you posted sample data and results - that really helps. But sometimes it also helps to have your table structures. And you really should attempt a solution yourself and post it so we can correct it for you.

Comment: Yes Thanks... too simple...  but for newbies... it's real...   can I make direct update with set from this result (new_unit_price) to old_unit_price.. wery good answer... I have juste a little reponse time from my server result 1'000'000 orders and 20'000 prices